# Выделяется ли "да" знаками препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

**Да()глупо,да()тяжело,да()долго,но имеет смысл.**

**Да()глупо.Да()тяжело.Да()долго.Но имеет смысл.**

Как в таких случаях расставляются знаки препинания?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все зависит от авторского смысла и вообще от широкого контекста.

Если это "да" имеет смысл "согласен", то оно отделяется запятой от остальной части. "Да" в этом случае утвердительная частица. Если судить только по приведенному фрагменту, этот случай наиболее вероятен. **Да, глупо, да, тяжело, да, долго, но имеет смысл**. Оставляю на совести автора вопрос, как может быть глупым то, что имеет смысл.

Если же это частица усилительная или вообще союз, то, естественно, дополнительных знаков не требуется.

***- Послушайте! Да это же аморально! Да глупо. Да тяжело. Но имеет смысл.***

Весьма искусственная конструкция, не отнюдь не невозможная в принципе.

Сравните у Пушкина.

*Ох, лето красное! любил бы я тебя,

Когда б не зной, да пыль, да комары, да мухи.*

Answer (score 1):

**Да, глупо, да, тяжело, да, долго, но смысл (в этом) есть.**

Утвердительно слово ***да*** всегда обособляется (в отличие от союза и частицы *да*).

Предложение немного отредактировано, но правильность его семантики надо смотреть по контексту.