# Конструкция «и да» в предложении. Функции и пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, союзы, авторская-пунктуация, частица

В книге Елены Звездной [**«Шепот в темноте»**](http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=67332&p=13) часто встречаются предложения с использованием **и да**. Вот некоторые из них.

1. *Оборотень в ответ на мою тираду улыбнулся. Широко, насмешливо **и да,** явно издевательски*.
2. *Такая белая кожа, черные волосы, совершенно удивительные глаза цвета чистого летнего неба. **И да** — ты для меня редкость, среди наших девушек практически нет брюнеток.*
3. *...как-то неожиданно поняла, что вопрос с моим согласием уже полностью решен, **и да,** мне предстоит оценить шарлотку и клубничный сок...*
4. *Ну и в завершение комедии — все пятеро прибыли сегодня в клан Волка, под охраной **и с да, с** пафосом.*

**И да** — что это за конструкция такая? Правильна ли пунктуация в предложениях?
В словарях и на нашем сайте (например, [Выделяется ли “да” знаками препинания?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/433757/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/433764#433764)) я подходящего ответа не нашла.

Comment: Не должно отличаться по пунктуации от "и действительно" или "и в самом деле".

Comment: Тогда получается, что последнее предложение будет выглядеть так: _...прибыли сегодня в клан Волка, под охраной и с действительно, с пафосом._  Или: _...прибыли сегодня в клан Волка, под охраной и с в самом деле, с пафосом._

Comment: Первое "с" там лишнее в обоих вариантах (пусть будет "излишне авторское").

Answer (score 6):

**Конструкция "и да"** действительно встречается  в текстах, причем с разным (ещё не устоявшимся)  графическим оформлением. Обособляется запятой, но часто и  тире, что означает паузу в речи.

**Каков смысл конструкции?**

Возможно, это размышление о справедливости последующего высказывания **и решение о том, что мысль является верной**: и да, действительно, несомненно, я в этом уверен.

Другой вариант ―  **возвращение к мысли собеседника и подтверждение её**.

Примеры:

**И да,** вы совершенно правы, все это может плохо закончиться.

Икона ― это подобие, это изображение, которое никогда не может быть совершенным, потому что изображение никогда не может совпадать с полнотой реальности, но достаточно реально, чтобы ударить нас в душу **и ― да,** приобщить нас к тому опыту, который вписан, врезан в эту икону.

Он опять оказался первым, ― упрямо повторил Натан, ― хотя **и да:** безоглядным и безрассудным.

Я принимаю все свои главные решения сердцем **и ― да**, с помощью интуиции.

Comment: Пунктуация в этих предложениях странная. Здесь «и да», как я понял,сближается с вводным словом.

Answer (score 2):

Конструкция **«и да»**  часто встречается в современной речи, но не везде выглядит уместной.  Писатели пытаются представить грамматику интересной и необычно построенной, но такое «украшательство» часто **ухудшает качество текста.**  И тогда не понимается его смысл,  а кому-то ои и вовсе кажется «речью из подворотни».
**Две основные функции сочетания** уже  были указаны, так что попробуем их оценить.

(1) **Это подтверждение чего-то ожидаемого**

Но я здесь не вижу **ни одного примера**, где сочетание «и да»  красиво и гармонично вписывалось бы в текст.

(2) **Это возвращение к мысли (вопросу) собеседника и подтверждение её**

Вот этот вариант **мне нравится больше**:  иногда он смотрится довольно неплохо и даже мило. В качестве примера  я приведу отрывок из книги **Холли Вебб  «Роуз и тайна магии».**

Там был совершенно очаровательный персонаж  — **белый волшебный кот**, (кстати, очень любящий сливки, но только самые лучшие, джерсейские). По сюжету целую группу детей спасли от злой волшебницы, и наш герой принимал в этом самое активное участие. Вот такой приведен **диалог:**

— *Он разговаривает! У тебя волшебный котик?  А можно его погладить?*

— *Спрашивайте меня, если вас не затруднит, —  надменно ответил Гус. —  Она мне не хозяйка. **И да, можно,** если у вас руки чистые.*

P.S. Честно говоря, сочетание "и да" с этим значением я и сама иногда **использую** в речи.