# Следует ли обособлять «нет» и «да» с двух сторон?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, частица

*Хотя, **нет,** думаю, необходимо согласовать этот вопрос с родителями.

И, **да,** занятия вчера я не посещала.*

Знатоки, требуется ваша помощь.

Answer (score 3):

Обычно такие предложения звучат в собственных рассуждениях.
**Чаще всего** в таких конструкциях запятая ставится только после *нет* и только после *да*.

[**Нет**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82) — частица, употребляется внутри речи для внесения поправки, отрицающей ранее сказанное. *Позвони мне завтра, нет, послезавтра.*

*Может быть, где-то есть большой старый сундук — и сказки сложены в нём аккуратной стопочкой? **Хотя нет,** им было бы очень скучно в сундуке…* (Валентин Лебедев).

> — Как ты думаешь, Вик, могли бы мы, к примеру, воспользоваться выходом через окно? Может, снаружи пожарная лестница есть, или труба водосточная, или по карнизу как-то пробраться можно к другому окну? **Хотя нет,** все окна на зиму уже законсервированы. Но проверить надо (Рина Осинкина).

**Да** — частица, употребляется при неожиданном воспоминании о чём-либо упущенном в предшествующем разговоре, при перемене темы разговора и т. п. Кстати, вот ещё. *Да, вот ещё что.*

***И да,** я понимаю, что романтизация — это во многом нормально и неизбежно* (Дарья Серенко).
***И да,** за это приходится чем-то платить* (Анастасия Искандер).
***И да,** вы совершенно правы, все это может плохо закончиться* (Андрей Константинов, Александр Поддьяков).

В зависимости от контекста (а его у нас нет) и от необходимости передать увеличенные паузы в речи, могут быть использованы и другие знаки препинания.

*Это надо вам у рыбаков искать. **Хотя нет!** Они теперь крабов тоже не ловят, у них артель, план* (Ю. О. Домбровский).
*Первое время я вообще не помню, как жила. **Хотя — нет…** К сожалению, помню. Как в театре шушукались за спиной* (Александр Мардань).
*Не буду врать… **Хотя нет:** не буду врать, будто совсем не буду врать* (Андрей Пермяков).
***Хотя нет ―** волосы после болезни сильно поредели и поседели* (Н. Б. Черных).

Дополнительно: [Конструкция «и да» в предложении. Функции и пунктуация](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/437617/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F).